# Batch Script to verify login credentials

Tags: authentication, batch-file, automation

I am writing a batch script for my department, that can perform some remote restart and connection verification functions. However, I want to ensure that the person using the batch script has active credentials. The start of the script is as follows for login information:L

```
:credentials
SET /p UN=Username: 
cls
SET /p PW=Password:
*login verification code here*
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
@echo off
color 02
goto :shutdownset1
) else (
if %errorlevel% == 1
echo Invalid Login Information!
pause
goto :credentials
```

This setup I am using to store the logon information as variables, that the user must enter, now I am having trouble finding the proper command to verify those credentials... I know already how to use the if and else statements with errorlevel argument, but I lack the initial command or commands to verify the username and password. Any thoughts.

Comment: do you think, it's a good idea to verify a password with batch? Everybody can read a batch script.

Comment: Because of what this batch file is doing, the people have to have proper credentials to be able to do it, and I didnt want a permanent storage of user account information in the batch. By using verification, I can make sure they are still valid users before hand, before this batch can successfully run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try to map a network drive with the provided credential ? like

```
set /P UN=Username
Set /P PW=Password
set computername=localhost

net use T: \\%computername%\c$ %PW% /user:%UN%
if  %errorlevel% NEQ 0 ( echo too bad)
```

Comment: After talking with some more guys, we are going with a different approach, but your answer solved the issue for other script files I was writing. thank you so much!

Comment: Lol glad to helped you anyway